# Android toolbar showing images of previously added fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-toolbar

I used toolbars in fragments instead of inflating it to activity.I am using different ImageViews in each toolbar layout.I was working fine. When I changed fragment transaction replace by add it is showing images of current layout images and previous fragment's images also.`transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);`What can I do?

I replaced replace by add since it showing some transparency while animating the second fragment from bottom.

This is how I added second fragment,

```
 Fragment newFragment = new DetailsFragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.splashfadeout);
    transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

if You use image different image in different fragment then you must hide or remove resourse onDestroy like it.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
    activity.mToolbarRightImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

if in which fragment you not use that ToolBarimage then on create of fragment you also hide that image.I faced this problem but i solved this way

```
  MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
    activity.mToolbarRightImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

If You want to use toolBar ImageView in each fragment , You make public in Mainactivty then you use above instruction

Comment: I inflated icons in first fragment using menu.xml